# JSONPath for object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have created this jsonPath like so:

```
json.SelectTokens("$.children[?(@.extension == 'ord')].name");
```

Which should work for this Json:

```
{
  "total":8,
  "page":1,
  "pages":1,
  "per_page":25,
  "previous":null,
  "next":null,
  "children":[
      {
        "id":599071309,
        "name":"S200-219842-20180522095501.ord",
        "path":"/eOrdering/GRE017/S200-219842-20180522095501.ord",
        "url":"/api/2.1/path/info/eOrdering/GRE017/S200-219842-20180522095501.ord",
        "links":1,
        "remote_status":null,
        "size":98,
        "items":0,
        "time":"2018-05-23T11:29:48",
        "isfile":true,
        "isdir":false,
        "extension":"ord",
        "mime":"application/unknown",
      },
      {
        "id":599071327,
        "name":"S200-219846-20180522095501.ord",
        "path":"/eOrdering/GRE017/S200-219846-20180522095501.ord",
        "url":"/api/2.1/path/info/eOrdering/GRE017/S200-219846-20180522095501.ord",
        "links":1,
        "remote_status":null,
        "size":271,
        "items":0,
        "time":"2018-05-23T11:29:49",
        "isfile":true,
        "isdir":false,
        "extension":"ord",
        "mime":"application/unknown",
      }
  ],
  "has_preview":false,
  "version":0,
  "is_shared":false
}
```

But sometimes I get this json:

```
{
  "total":2,
  "page":1,
  "pages":1,
  "per_page":25,
  "previous":null,
  "next":null,
  "size":3693,
  "items":0,
  "time":"2018-04-05T10:28:46",
  "isfile":false,
  "isdir":true,
  "children":[
    {
        "id":534206951,
        "name":"Inbox",
        "path":"/eOrdering/TAP006/Inbox",
        "url":"/api/2.1/path/info/eOrdering/TAP006/Inbox",
        "links":1,
        "remote_status":null,
        "size":0,
        "items":0,
        "time":"2017-10-17T07:50:08",
        "isfile":false,
        "isdir":true,
        "extension":"",
        "mime":"application/x-directory",
    }
  ]
}
```

So I would like to create a jsonPath expression that checks to see if the children are files (by checking the **isFile** property) and if it is, then does it have an extension. But I would like it to ignore anything else.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Json path selects certain json nodes, it does not check anything. So what do you want to select? Only files, only with extension or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a minute after creating it. I just updated the jsonPath to be this:

```
var names = json.SelectTokens("$.children[?(@.isfile == true && @.extension == '" + extension + "')].name");
```

And that was it, it started working correctly.